# race condition between creation and display of datatable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having a race condition between when I create a datatable and when I display it. Is there a way to make sure the datatable exists before displaying it. 
the flow is

1. Create data from reactiveValues List of List
2. Display this new data

---

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(foreach)
library(DT)

 ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("table"))

 server <- function(input, output, session) {

   values <- reactiveValues()

   # Adding lists dynamically
   values[["A"]] <- list(info = 1, data = data.table(i = 1, j = 2))
   values[["B"]] <- list(info = 10, data = data.table(i = 10, j = 20))

   observe({
     # Update data everytime new elements are added to values
     # This is just adding all data.tables as rows to one data.table
     data <- rbindlist(foreach(list = reactiveValuesToList(values)) %do% list$data)
   })

   output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(data)

}

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

the data is created inside an observe function and then rendered using DT::renderDataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` should be reactive as well,

```
observe({
    values$data <- rbindlist(foreach(list = reactiveValuesToList(values)) %do% list$data)
})

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(values$data)
```

Comment: Thankyou, So a value that depends on a reactiveValue doesn't automatically make it reactive. It has to be specially made reactive

Comment: Yea, you only need `<-` instead of `<<-` though becase the reactiveValues are not copy on modify like normal R listsl.